# Depois do clear:both, div com float não alinha corretamente

Tags: css, float

Estou fazendo um site responsivo e estou usando “float” e “clear: both” pra colocar as divs nos seus lugares. Mas depois de usar “clear: both”, a “div6” não alinha corretamente no lado direito.

Para esclarecer: [image: ver a imagem]
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
<div class="div4">4</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div5">5</div>
<div class="div6">6</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clear
{
clear:both;
}

.container
{
width: 100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
display:table;
background-color:#CCC;
}

.div1
{
background-color:#FF0;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div1
{
background-color:#FF0;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div2
{
background-color:#FC0;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div2
{
background-color:#FC0;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div3
{
background-color:#F90;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div3
{
background-color:#F90;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div4
{
background-color:#F60;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div4
{
background-color:#F60;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div5
{
background-color:#0C6;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:80px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div5
{
background-color:#0C6;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:80px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}

.div6
{
background-color:#396;
position:relative;
width: 50%;
height:40px;
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.div6
{
background-color:#396;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:0;
}
}
```

Eu imagino que a solução para isso seja simples mas não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema. Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Posso te fazer uma pergunta? Já que vc esta na faze inicial do projeto, ainda na construção do grid, Pq vc não opta por fazer esse grid com Flex e não com float? Float eh uma técnica arcaica por assim dizer, e o Flex tem uma serie de vantagens, além das classes de alinhamento etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que posso dizer é que o seu `float` está funcionando perfeitamente, só que não da forma que vc esperava...

Repare que vc colocou um `div` com `clear:both`, logo depois da `div 4`, com isso vc cria uma "linha de quebra" que limpa o fluxo do conteúdo e joga tudo que vier depois da div 4 para outra linha de baixo e tem outro fluxo de conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que na classe da `div` que faz o clear eu coloquei uma borda, assim fica fácil de vc visualizar onde ela "corta" o fluxo. Nada que vier abaixo dessa `div` clear vc vai conseguir passar para "linha de cima"... a não ser com gambiarra... Que foi o que eu fiz nesse modelo abaixo apenas para te mostrar que é possível, mas não é indicado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então não é por que vc pode que vc deve... Como falei no comentário, aproveite que vc está no inicio e considere usar `Flexbox` no sei projeto!

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
.clear {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: #FF0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div1 {
        background-color: #FF0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.div2 {
    background-color: #FC0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div2 {
        background-color: #FC0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.div3 {
    background-color: #F90;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div3 {
        background-color: #F90;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.div4 {
    background-color: #F60;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div4 {
        background-color: #F60;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.div5 {
    background-color: #0C6;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div5 {
        background-color: #0C6;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.div6 {
    background-color: #396;
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    /* float: right; */
    /* margin-right: 0; */
    
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(40px * 3);
    right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div6 {
        background-color: #396;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: initial;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">1</div>
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
    <div class="div4">4</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="div5">5</div>
    <div class="div6">6</div>
</div>
```

---

**DICA**

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta hugocsl foi bem esclarecedora. Realmente a solução é uma "gambi" pois ela calcula a altura das divs acima para posicionar a div6. No meu caso acredito que não seria a solução ideal pois as divs acima podem variar em quantidade e altura. Mas a dica do FLEXBOX parece uma boa. Não conhecia esse recurso e já estou navegando e estudando para aplicar. Agradeço seu tempo e sua ajuda que foi muito valiosa. Grande abraço!

Comment: @JohnSnowDad cara tem muito material sobre FlexBox por ai, vc vai ver que é bem fácil de usar e mais flexível que o float. O Bootstrap mesmo usa Flex no Grid deles. Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma e vc acha que o assunto está resolvido considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com a pergunta aberta pendente mesmo já tendo sido esclarecida. E se tiver alguma dúvida com Flex no futuro posta ai que a gente te ajuda!